# Why do I get this error "expression must be an lvalue or a function designator" for some of my data members?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that prints whatever I feed it from the class I created. I can only get some of my class object data members to work with my print function.

I have tried using pointers and references in some source codes I found online but they didn't work. After working on this problem for about a week now I feel like I have tried everything.

```
void print(string* object);


enum Degree { SECURITY = 1, NETWORKING = 2, SOFTWARE = 3};
class Student {
    public:
        Student(string ID, string first, string last, string Email, int Age, int days1, int days2, int days3, Degree StudentDegree) {
            studentID = ID;
            firstName = first;
            lastName = last;
            email = Email;
            age = Age;
            daysTillComplete[0] = { days1 };
            daysTillComplete[1] = { days2 };
            daysTillComplete[2] = { days3 };
            studentDegree = StudentDegree;
            return;
        }

        string getID() const;
        void setID(string ID);

        string getFirst() const;
        void setFirst(string ID);

        string getLast() const;
        void setLast(string ID);

        string getEmail() const;
        void setEmail(string ID);

        int getAge() const;
        void setAge( int Age);

        int getdays1();
        int getdays2();
        int getdays3();
        void setDaysTilComplete(int days, int days1, int days2);

        Degree getDegree() const;
        void setDegree(Degree degreeType);

    private:
        string studentID = "No name"; 
        string firstName = "No name";
        string lastName = "No name";
        string email = "No name";
        int age = 7;
        int daysTillComplete[3];
        Degree studentDegree = NETWORKING;
};

void print(string* object) {
    cout << *object << endl;
}
string Student::getID() const {
    return studentID;
}
string Student::getFirst() const {
    return firstName;
}
string Student::getLast() const {
    return lastName;
}
string Student::getEmail() const {
    return email;
}
int Student::getAge() const {
    return age;
}
int Student::getdays1() {
    return daysTillComplete[0];
}
int Student::getdays2() {
    return daysTillComplete[1];
}
int Student::getdays3() {
    return daysTillComplete[2];
}
Degree Student::getDegree() const {
    return studentDegree;
}
void Student::setID(string ID) {
    studentID = ID;
}
void Student::setFirst(string first) {
    firstName = first;
}
void Student::setLast(string last) {
    lastName = last;
}
void Student::setEmail(string Email) {
    email = Email;
}
void Student::setAge(int studentAge) {
    age = studentAge;
}
void Student::setDaysTilComplete(int days1, int days2, int days3) {
    daysTillComplete[0] = days1;
    daysTillComplete[1] = days2;
    daysTillComplete[2] = days3;
}
void Student::setDegree(Degree degreeType) {
    studentDegree = degreeType;
}

int main() {
    Student vallery("A1", "Vallery", "Williams", "vallery.a.williams1234@gmail.com",21,52,28,32,NETWORKING);    
    print(&vallery.getID());
    print(&vallery.getFirst());
    print(&vallery.getLast());
    print(&vallery.getEmail());

    //print(&vallery.getAge());     <--- will not compile if this statement is in the program
    //print(&vallery.getdays1());       <--- will not compile if this statement is in the program
    ////print(&vallery.getdays2());     <--- will not compile if this statement is in the program
    ////print(&vallery.getdays3());     <--- will not compile if this statement is in the program
    //print(&vallery.getDegree());      <--- will not compile if this statement is in the program

    cin.get();


    return 0;
}
```

My expected results for example print(vallery.getFirst); would be print vallery. That works, but when I do print(vallery.getAge); it should be 21 but I can't even compile it because I get the "expression must be an l-value or function designator" error. Also using int instead of string for the data type of the print function doesn't work either. I must be using something incorrectly. Can someone point me in the right direction? After a bunch of research I haven't found any solutions.

Comment: Did you `#include` any of the necessary headers ?   Edit you question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation in the shown code so that it's readable. The broken indentation makes the shown code very hard to read. The first step to figuring out any compilation problem is to understand the code, and without logical indentation this is mostly impossible. If you'd like to have the best chance of someone taking the time and figuring out your problem, you should make it as easy as possible for everyone else to understand your code.

Comment: The lines you say work [are not valid](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v1k1VB). If those compile and the others don't, your compiler is doing something weird, possibly because of the flags you gave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things are are probably going wrong with this code.

The most obvious is that your print function expects a `string*`. The calls that fail are those where you try and give the function something that is not a `string*`. For example, `getAge()` returns a int, where you are taking the address of the returned int. So you are trying to call print(int*) which then is failing. To solve this you can either using templating or have overloads. Here is a recommended template function:

```
template <typename T>
print (const T& _object) 
{
 cout << _object << endl;
}
```

A second problem, which is what is masking this first error comes from the fact you are taking a ptr instead of a reference (or a const reference as in my template function). If you want to print something, you want it to definitely be there and not a `nullptr`. So use references. In saying this, I think the ones that you say will work, definitely shouldn't work (even though they are string*'s) under any sane compiler. Perhaps the current error is hiding those errors.

The error *“expression must be an lvalue or a function designator”* comes from the fact that you are trying to take the address of an r-value. That is a value that is temporary  and/or has not been bound to a name. Your getters return a copy of the value stored in your student object and this value has no address. You are trying to get the address of an addressless value, hence the error that it must be lvalue.

To solve this: Firstly don't use pointers, use a const reference. Secondly, have your getters return a const reference for objects. For example,

```
const string& Student::getID() const;
```

If your print function takes a const reference, it is able to handle a temporary variables for the cases where you return an `int` or other primitive type. Since your other getters return a reference to an addressable value, the print function can also take this reference without having to needlessly copy the values.

Comment: It's OK for the getters to return by value

Comment: @M It is 'OK'', but there is no downside and only benefits to returning a const reference rather than a value.

Comment: Downsides include that it makes it easier for the caller to create a dangling reference; and for the caller to break encapsulation by casting and writing the string

Comment: @M.M Yer good points - I guess it's more, there are not many downside unless you plan to cast constness away or save the reference for later use.

Comment: Returning a reference also restricts your ability to change the implementation of the class. In non-trivial classes, it's quite possible to face a decision between caching something or computing it on the fly. Returning a reference complicates the latter. On top of this point, it's possible for a reference to alias another variable in scope, which can limit optimization in some cases (revolving around writes not being independent). It's hard to relate these to an example like this question, but they do exist and should be considered whenever this decision is made.

Comment: Huge RESPECT to @Bar Stool . I wasn't familiar with templates so I had to do some research. The first video I clicked on basically wrote the code for me. Knowledge gap filled!